# gcc inline asm and pointer index

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I want to write a 32 bit value to a indexed pointer via gcc and inline asm.

This is what it should do:

```
this->screenPtr[ x + drawY * this->w ] = col;
```

And here's one of my trys:

```
            asm (
                "movl   %2,     %%eax;"
                "imull  %3;"
                "addl   %1,     %%eax;"
                "movl   %4,     (%0 , %%eax, 4);"

                : "=r" (*this->screenPtr)
                : "r" (x), "r" (drawY), "r" (this->w), "r" (col)
                : "%eax"
                 );
```

How it's done?
Thank you.

Oh, I can edit here :)  (someone asked for more code)

```
    class raycaster{
        public:
        int     isInit;
        long*   screenPtr;
        int     w;
        int     h;
        int     mapWidth;
        int     mapHeight;
        cam_t   camera;
        ...


    (xLoop)
      (calculations)
        for (int drawY = drawStart; drawY < drawEnd; drawY ++ ) {

            int texY;
            long col;
            asm volatile(
                //int d = (drawY * 2 - h + lineHeight) * 128;
                "movl   %1,         %%eax;" // mov drawY in eax
                "shll   $1,         %%eax;" // * 2
                "subl   %2,         %%eax;" // - h
                "addl   %3,         %%eax;" // + lineHeight
                "movl   $128,       %%ebx;"
                "imull  %%ebx;"             // * 128

                //int texY = ((d * TEX_HEIGHT) / lineHeight) / 256;
                "imull  %4;"                // * TEX_HEIGHT
                "movl   %3,         %%ebx;"
                "idivl  %%ebx;"              // : lineHeight
                "movl   $0,         %%edx;"
                "movl   $256,       %%ebx;"
                "idivl  %%ebx;"             // : 256

                //[texX + texY * TEX_HEIGHT];
                "movl   %4,         %%ebx;"
                "imull  %%ebx;"             // * TEX_HEIGHT
                "addl   %5,         %%eax;" // + lineHeight

                "movl   %%eax,      %0;"
                : "=r" (texY)
                : "r"  (drawY), "m" (h), "r" (lineHeight), "r" (TEX_HEIGHT), "m" (texX)
                : "%eax", "%ebx", "%edx"
                );

            col = this->textureMemory[textureNumber - 1][texY];
```

This is how I done col, now I want to combine it, so that it can write it direcly in the buffer.

```
            /*
            asm (
                "movl   %2,     %%eax;"
                "imull  %3;"
                "addl   %1,     %%eax;"
                "movl   %4,     (%0 , %eax, 4);"
                //"movl   %%eax,  %0;"

                : "=r" (*screenPtr)
                : "r" (x), "r" (drawY), "r" (this->w), "r" (col)
                : "%eax"
                 );
            */

            this->screenPtr[ x + drawY * this->w ] = col;
        }
```

The "extra "code is may more confusing, concentrate to the first snipped and the question.

Edit 2:

If somebody read the comments, there we was searching for the cause of the slow speed. This code is better and reaches the speed of my assembly code. The thing I have changed is, that I've removed the temporary variables to avoid memory access.

```
            int texY = texX + (((drawY * 2 - h + lineHeight) * 128* TEX_HEIGHT) / lineHeight) / 256  * TEX_HEIGHT;

            long col = this->textureMemory[textureNumber - 1][texY];
            this->screenPtr[ x + drawY * this->w ] = col;
```

Comment: We need a more complete example... For example, what type is `screenPtr`? And why do you possibly think that you can "beat" the compiler at this sort of thing?

Comment: screenPtr is a long* to a 32 bit screenbuffer, x is the actual x coordinate, drawY is y, this->w screen width and col the color. class raycaster{
    public:
    int     isInit;
    long*   screenPtr;
    int     w;
 
..and so on. The texture reading i've successfully written in asm, col is the result. (This was a speed up to ~ 5 times, this is why I want to convert more code to asm.)

Comment: Speedup of 5x from an optimised compile? Really? Still, we need something that can be compiled...

Comment: As I see idivl with 256, I can immediately say that you are NOT compiling with -O2, because the compiler will translate this to a shift right of 8, which is MUCH faster than idivl.

Comment: Thanks :D I'd shift left and was wondering why it don't work. I will replace it with shifting. But answer my question now :p

Comment: To be able to answer your question, I have to first build a program to test it (since I'm not THAT hot at writing inline assembler, it's been a few years [10+] since I did it for a living). And since your code isn't anywhere near complete, it will take me at least 15-20 minutes to get there. And of course, chances are that someone else answers first...

Comment: Btw: If anybody want to tell me how "this->textureMemory[textureNumber - 1][texY];" is done in asm, go ahead. textureMemory is an long* array.

Comment: What exactly are your optimisation settings for the compiler? I'm VERY surprised you get such poor results from the compiler. With -O2, it should do better than your inline assembler. It's not very cleverly using instructions available. And I'm afraid I'm giving up on finding you an answer. It's just too hard to recreate some code that does the right thing.

Comment: Ok but thanks :) btw, I've updated the division.

Comment: I _THINK_ your problem is that you have the wrong indirection level on your `this->screenPtr`, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: The -O is nearly affectless. Only with -march=pentium4 I get much better results (really much better), but this is related to the floating point instructions in the x-loop and SSE/2/3. I believe, the problem with the drawing is simply, that the code is exucuted for everx pixel, 786432 times for 1024*768 :/ and I wont to remove my deficiency with SSE.

Comment: Since you are not even using inline assembler to do the the loop itself, I believe that -O2 or -O3 would give you better than your hand assemblered results - particularly using `div` and `mul` inside the loop is clearly signs that the compiler isn't doing a very good job. Or you're used a VERY ancient version of gcc - but even gcc 3.x would do what I just described in -O2 at the very least.

Comment: I'll update my answer, i've done something.